# How to delete until (and not including) the last char on the line

Tags: vim, shortcut

I would like to delete a sequence ending with plenty parenthesis and rather than count the exact number of parenthesis to do a d[count]f), I want to delete up to the before last character in a line.

I tried dt$ but with no success.

EDIT: Eventually, can we exclude more characters ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly you mean here by "sentence"? Is this the same as in `:h sentence` or something else?

Comment: my question is not specific to a text object as defined in vim. I would like to delete up to the end of line except the last character that I want to keep. The last character is not necessarily particular like a period, question mark or exclamation mark. He might even occur in the part of the line I want to delete. Must I type a delete command ? Or is there a way to tell vim, I want to delete up to [count] characters **before** the line in normal mode ?

Comment: So can you **re-write** your question then, so it finally become clear what you're asking about? It's not "move", and it's not "a sentence". It's "delete until (not including) the last char on the line" as far as I understand it now.

Comment: Is sequence more clear than sentence ? I deleted two sentences to make the question shorter for other viewers. I added a question too, as it seems a logical one to ask next.

Comment: It will do, I guess. On excluding several chars, I believe it's better not to mess with some sophisticated text objects, but simply do it in Visual mode, like `v$hh...d` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as I see the real question is "How to delete until (and not including) the last char on the line.

And the answer is: `dv$`. See `:h exclusive` and `:h o_v`.

Comment: I like how this is  simple, but it doesn't work in vs code :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [marks](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark) or visual selection. For example with marks:

```
ma$d`a
```

Splitting in commands:

```
ma Mark the current cursor position with mark a
$ Go to the last character in the line
d`a Delete back to the mark a
```

If you need to preserve a few characters at the end of the line add `Nh` after `$`. E.g.:

```
ma$3hd`a
```

Visual selection:

```
v$3hx
```

Define a command with one required argument:

```
function! DelToEOL(n)
    execute 'normal v$' . string(a:n + 1) . 'hx'
endfunction

command -nargs=1 DelToEOL :call DelToEOL(<args>)
```

`+ 1` is required because visual selection selects the current character which should be excluded.

Comment: This seems almost ok to me. I avoid using marks for things I want to delete, as it may erase previous marks and I like to keep charachters for mnemonic alias of parts of my code (m for main, and generally the first letter of the name of a function, method or class I usually jump to).
 visual selection like 
`v$hd`
is sufficient to me. How can I make it into a command with a counter ?

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I am sorry for the misunderstood of the problem I led you into due to my confusing title. I regret not being able to accept more than one answer to thank you accordingly, since you did answer my problem as staten before editing.